# spring session redis ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP not working

Tags: redis, spring-session

according to the document https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/api.html

If you use @EnableRedisHttpSession, managing the SessionMessageListener and enabling the necessary Redis Keyspace events is done automatically. However, in a secured Redis enviornment, the config command is disabled. This means that Spring Session cannot configure Redis Keyspace events for you. To disable the automatic configuration, add ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP as a bean.

```
implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:2.7.0'
implementation 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.2.0.RELEASE'

@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfiguration
                = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("ip", port);
        standaloneConfiguration.setPassword("password");
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(standaloneConfiguration);
    }
}

@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 60 * 1)
public class HttpRedisSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }
}

@Component
public class RedisSessionListener {

    @EventListener
    public void onCreate(SessionCreatedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("create!!");
        System.out.println(event);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onDestroy(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("destory!!");
        System.out.println(event);
    }

}
```

but

like the picture below
I still receive the expiry event.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you may click into the source code of `org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction`, then you will see it is actually a default implementation of ConfigureRedisAction;
you will see the implementation just fetch the configuration of notify function and ensure the redis instance has been well configured of notify ability;

And the NO_OP just makes this "ensure" action not executed, the actual function still depends on the configuration at the redis instance side.